# How to create .mobi / .azw3 from latex document?

Tags: conversion

Is it possible to use [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com) to convert latex into .mobi or .azw3?

Comment: Possibly answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub